# Coletar todos os Extras de um Intent

Tags: java, android, bundle

Existe alguma forma de descobrir quais são todos os Extras de um Intent!

**CONTEXTO**:

Tenho um app que recebe url's compartilhadas pelos demais apps:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {

    final String url_ = i.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if(null != url_){
        urls.add(url_);
    }
}
```

Queria saber quais paramêtros além do `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` este `Intent` têm?

Comment: Como assim todos os `Extras`? Você quer saber qual os extras que foram registrados usando `Intent` ou todos os `statics` relacionado ao `Intent`?

Comment: Todos os  extras que foram registrados usando  a Intent

Comment: Veja a resposta, fiz uma edição inserindo a parte dos extras registrados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para quem ainda não está familiarizado, as [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)'s possibilitam que informações possam ser transmitidas de uma tela para outra, conforme o usuário navega pela aplicação.

> Uma *intent* é uma descrição abstrata de uma operação a ser realizada.

De acordo com [a documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), segue abaixo os valores atuais do tipo `EXTRA_[...]` que podem ser usados como dados extras via `putExtra (String, Bundle)` utilizando a classe `Intent`. Lembrando que não são somente estes que podem ser passados via `Intent`. Veja:

- EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT
- EXTRA_BCC
- EXTRA_CC
- EXTRA_CHANGED_COMPONENT_NAME
- EXTRA_DATA_REMOVED
- EXTRA_DOCK_STATE
- EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_HE_DESK
- EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_LE_DESK
- EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_CAR
- EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_DESK
- EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED
- EXTRA_DONT_KILL_APP
- EXTRA_EMAIL
- EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
- EXTRA_INTENT
- EXTRA_KEY_EVENT
- EXTRA_ORIGINATING_URI
- EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER
- EXTRA_REFERRER
- EXTRA_REMOTE_INTENT_TOKEN
- EXTRA_REPLACING
- EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON
- EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE
- EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT
- EXTRA_STREAM
- EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME
- EXTRA_SUBJECT
- EXTRA_TEMPLATE
- EXTRA_TEXT
- EXTRA_TITLE
- EXTRA_UID

Para resgatar todos valores salvos no `Intent` você pode fazer um `foreach` percorrendo o `bundle` usando `keySet()`. Veja abaixo:

```
if (bundle != null) {
    for (String chave : bundle.keySet()) {
        Object value = bundle.get(chave);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s (%s)", chave, 
             value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Resposta ficou bem legal, mas eu só mudaria um detalhe: a primeira frase dá margem a interpretação de que somente esses valores podem ser passados via Intent, mas eles são parâmetros públicos, para intents específicos. A priori qualquer chave pode ser passados via extras.

Comment: @Wakim obrigado, editei e melhorei para que ninguém possa vir confundir.